# Foreign key fields in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

What is best way to save foreign key fields without letting user to select from the parent model?
Let say i have these models

Models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoFiled(primary_key=True)

class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.AutoFiled(primary_key=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank=True)
```

Forms

```
Class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        Model = Product
        fields = ['name']
```

Views

```
def create_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved!', 'alert-success')
            return redirect('products')
   else:
        return render(request, ' manageproducts/create_product.html', {'form':form})
```

I want a user to enter only a name but in the database i want a form to post category_id, brand_id and name. How can i do that?

Comment: How could user know your products name in advance? in a list?

Comment: There's a form user enter a product name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **`HiddenInput`** widget,  which would render as `<input type="hidden" ...>`. But this requires some js code to provide the correct `category`  and `brand` values before the form submission

```
from django import forms

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('category', 'brand', 'name')
        widgets = {
            'category': forms.HiddenInput(),
            'brand': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

#### UPDATE

```
def update_product(request, pk=None):
    try:
        product = Product.ojbects.get(pk=pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist：
        raise Http404

    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, instance=product)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            # category and brand will be unchanged
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved!', 'alert-success')
            return redirect('products')
    else:
        return render(request, ' manageproducts/create_product.html', {'form':form})
```

Without selecting `category` and `brand` is only reasonable for updating, for creation of new product, you **have to** select a new category and brand, otherwise it will break [Foreign Key Constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)

Comment: How do i set the view?

Comment: @EricksonKitoz view is as the same before, `category` and `brand` will not be displayed but will be submitted along with `product name`, just make sure that your `category` and `brand` exists in database, otherwise, an `IntegrityError` would raise

Comment: @EricksonKitoz if you only submit `product name`, how could you know which `category and brand` this product belongs to in frontend?

Comment: I used those models as example, what i need is to submit the fk fields without user to select

Comment: I want to relate Product model with Category  and Brand model

Comment: In this case, your foreign key must aleady exists beforehead, updatef